# How to assign a reference to a shared pointer to another shared pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am refactoring some code which uses raw pointers to use shared pointers instead.
In the original code, there is a raw pointer to a list object, let's call it EntityList
I have typedefed a shared pointer to an EntityList in the EntityList.h file, as follows:

```
using EntityList_ptr = std::shared_ptr<EntityList>;
```

In the code to refactor, there is one place where the list can be set to one of several types of list.

Here is where the lists are created:

```
EntityList_ptr typeZeroList = EntityList_ptr (new ZeroList);
EntityList_ptr typeOneList = EntityList_ptr (new OneList);
EntityList_ptr typeTwoList = EntityList_ptr (new TwoList);
EntityList_ptr typeThreeList = EntityList_ptr (new ThreeList);
```

And here is where I set the list to the appropriate type:

```
setList (int type) {
    EntityList** list;

if (type == 0) {
    list = &typeZeroList;
} else if (type ==1) {
    list = &typeOneList;
} else if (type ==2) {
    list = &typeTwoList;
} else {
    list = &typeThreeList;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to refactor this. Here is my stab at it (I tried three different approaches in the if-else part below.:

```
setList (int type) {
    std::shared_ptr<EntityList_ptr> list;

    if (type == 0) {
        list = &typeZeroList;
    } else if (type ==1) {
        list = typeOneList.get();
    } else if (type ==2) {
        list = &(typeTwoList.get());
    } else {
        list = std::shared_ptr<Entity> (typeThreeList.get());
    }
```

None of the above approaches work. I've tried various others too, but they all amount to stabbing in the dark without knowing what I am doing. Any ideas as to what I should do and explanations why would be welcome.

Comment: That sounds like a design issue. Why exactly do you want shared_ptr to shared_ptr? Why shared_ptr needs an owner for itself? Should `list` own a copy of the original shared_ptr or the same shared_ptr that you already have?

Comment: The situation is unclear because we do not see what role `list` serves in the overall code. Perhaps you could summarize that role in your question's text? It is possible that `list` should *not* be converted to a smart pointer. There are still uses for raw, non-owning pointers in some code. Perhaps this is one of them? Or perhaps some other substitution is called for? Did you consider `EntityList_ptr * list` or -- since it looks like null is not an option -- `EntityList_ptr & list`?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, even if my post was unclear. I have just spent about an hour writing up a sample program to make it clearer, but Remy below posted the answer before I could edit the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you replaced `EntityList*` with `EntityList_ptr` elsewhere in your code, you can do the exact same thing here. `EntityList**` would simply become `EntityList_ptr*`, eg:

```cpp
setList (int type) {
    EntityList_ptr* list;

    if (type == 0) {
        list = &typeZeroList;
    } else if (type ==1) {
        list = &typeOneList;
    } else if (type ==2) {
        list = &typeTwoList;
    } else {
        list = &typeThreeList;
    }

    // use *list as needed...
}
```

Taking the address of a variable of type `T` with the `&` operator produces a pointer of type `T*` <sup>1</sup>.  In this case, `T` is `EntityList_ptr`.

<sup>1: provided `T` does not override `operator&`, which `std::shared_ptr` does not.</sup>

So, since `typeXXXList` are `EntityList_ptr` variables, taking their addresses with the `&` operator produce `EntityList_ptr*` pointers.